# AWS BatchDELETE didn't delete files from S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3

I don't understand why some files have been deleted from AWS S3 Bucket and some files not.
Here is my function to delete:

```
func (s *S3Manager) Delete(keys []string) error {
    objects := make([]s3manager.BatchDeleteObject, len(keys))

    for i, v := range keys {
        objects[i] = s3manager.BatchDeleteObject{
            Object: &s3.DeleteObjectInput{
                Key:    aws.String(v),
                Bucket: s.bucket, // this is aws.String already
            },
        }
    }

    if err := s.remover.Delete(aws.BackgroundContext(), &s3manager.DeleteObjectsIterator{
        Objects: objects,
    }); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil

}
```

Make always the same - adding some photos, and then trying to delete them. Some photos deleted perfectly, some - not.
Maybe someone can help me with advice?
Looking forward to any of your reply

Update:

```
func NewS3Manager(accessKeyID, secretAccessKey, region, bucket, assetsDomain string) (*S3Manager, error) {
    creds := credentials.Value{
        AccessKeyID:     accessKeyID,
        SecretAccessKey: secretAccessKey,
    }

    sess, err := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
        Region:      aws.String(region),
        Credentials: credentials.NewStaticCredentialsFromCreds(creds),
    })
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed create aws session: %w", err)
    }

    return &S3Manager{
        remover:      s3manager.NewBatchDelete(sess),
        bucket:       aws.String(bucket),
    }, nil
}
```

Comment: How are you populating the list of keys? Does it include *all* of the objects that you intend to delete?

Comment: @jamod yes, the slice include only keys for the S3 bucket.

Comment: Do you have versioning enabled in S3 bucket?

Comment: @PiyushPatil versioning is not enabled

Comment: @jamod yes, there present in the `key` list key that was not deleted by Delete request. I'am not sure what can i print, because error gives me nil, and seems that work properly. I'm trying to delete 2 items at a time. What is the question that sometimes it deleted files, and sometimes - not. Even if the files are the same...

Comment: Can be the problem because someone used this file while was making a deletion and the command delayed until the file willn't be free to delete?

Comment: Deleted my prior comment, confusing DynamoDB and S3 requests. What is `remover`? Did you initialize it with `s3manager.NewBatchDelete(...)`? Add the code for that. On your question if S3 waits to delete object if object in use, I don't know how S3 works under the covers but if you got an OK response to the delete request, then the object was deleted (or did not exist at the time of deletion).

Comment: @jamod updated the first post

Answer (score 0):

You are using V1, maybe you should use V2 of the GO sdk.
As there is no batch delete, you have to range through.
Running example including version delete here: https://github.com/megaproaktiv/s3deleteversion

Comment: @GernotGiawe in your example used S3CLient, in my project I'm using S3Manager... SeManager Here is the documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/s3/s3manager/#BatchDelete

Comment: The S3 Manager is part of the older AWS SDK v1. I am using v2 as you see in the imports. The newer version (hopefully) should be more stable than the old v1.